# Para qué sirve esto, ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:= -32?

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy aprendiendo macros y en mi código aparece esto:

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:= -32
```

aunque lo borro, no cambia nada que pueda notar en mi código.

Comment: Recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a SO.

Ese comando hace que la ventana en Excel suba o baje. Suele salir mucho cuando se usa el grabador de macros, y vas seleccionando celdas con el ratón, y moviéndote arriba/abajo de la hoja mientras grabas.

Por eso al eliminarlo no lo notas.

> **[Método Window.SmallScroll (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.window.smallscroll)**

Comment: Muchas gracias! :)